# How to bulk upload events into Outlook Calendar via a csv file while preserving line breaks in the description?

Tags: html, csv, outlook, bulk-load

I upload Outlook Calendar events via CSV files on a regular basis. I am familiar with that process, however, I have not been able to preserve line breaks in the description. Ideally, I would like to be able to use HTML code to write the event description with proper formatting.

I have tried using `ALT-ENTER` to create line breaks and they are preserved in the CSV file, however, in Outlook, the line breaks are remove. I assume this is because of the plain text setting.

I have searched Google and Microsoft for a way to change the default to HTML with no success. I did notice that when I manually create an event, the default format is HTML.

I attempted to use HTML code, and that was partially successful. The following text is what I typed into the CSV field:

```html
<html>This is the first line of instruction. <br>
This is the second line of instruction. <br>
This is the final line of instruction. </html>
```

This did preserve the line breaks, but it also printed the tags. The resulting description in the Outlook event was exactly what I typed above. The result I would like to see in the Outlook event is below:

```
This is the first line of instruction.
This is the second line of instruction.
This is the final line of instruction.
```